# How do I update the Kops config from a yaml file?

Tags: kops

I've created a cluster from an yaml file using `kops create -f cluster.yaml`. At a later point, how can I edit this file directly and update the config rather than using `kops edit...`?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Do you want to edit the yaml and then apply changes?

Comment: Yes exactly that

Comment: Why not kops edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the below instead of doing `kops edit`

`kops replace -f cluster.yaml`

- helps available when you simply check with 
  `kops --help` or 
  `kops replace --help`